# How can I validate / check if string value exists in Firebase database (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've created AutoCompleteTextView for Ingredient, it works perfect. The DB save also works, I've tested it without validation.
If Ingredient exists in Firebase db I want to add recipe to DB.
For example if `RecipeIngredients="milk"` recipe should be saved to DB.

Here's my code.

```
DatabaseReference ingDBref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ingredients");
DatabaseReference databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Recipes");

public void addRecipe(){
        final String RecipeName=RecipeNameEditText.getText().toString();
        final String RecipePrepareTime=PrepareTimeEditText.getText().toString();        
        final String RecipeIngredients=IngredientsACTV.getText().toString();
        final String RecipeDescription=DescriptionEditText.getText().toString();
        final String RecipeDifficulty=DifficultySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        key=databaseReference.push().getKey();

        ingDBref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(data.child(RecipeIngredients).getValue()!=null){                   

                        Recipes recipes=new Recipes(key,RecipeName,RecipeDifficulty,RecipePrepareTime,RecipeIngredients,RecipeDescription);
                        databaseReference.child(key).setValue(recipes);
                        Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this,"Saved...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    else{
                        IngredientsACTV.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this,"Error...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

[Firebase DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g26AI.jpg)

[image]

Comment: What is the error in your code?

Comment: it always executing the "else" statement

Comment: What's the value of `RecipeIngredients`? Can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded value for that?

Comment: if I try for example `RecipeIngredients="milk"` it's still triggering only the else part.
The true part isn't executing. Not even once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(data.child("ingredientName").getValue().equals(RecipeIngredients))
```

Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mDatabase.child("Ingredients")
                    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                          String value=map.get("IngredientName"); 
                          // here will be your value of IngredientName

                          if(value.equals("Milk"){
                           // do something
                           }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            myDialog.CancelProgressDialog();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            myDialog.CancelProgressDialog();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            myDialog.CancelProgressDialog();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            myDialog.CancelProgressDialog();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are looping through the whole object. If the condition has been met, then you you set that value, if not then the else part is triggered for each of the remaining elements.

To solve this you can remove the else part if not needed or you need to use the `exists()` method provided by Firebase. To achieve this, just attach a listener on the same database reference and check if that child exists.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried this way `if(data.child(RecipeIngredients).exists())` . The results was also the same.

Comment: You need to use it on the specific child. That key should be a String and not an object.

Comment: `RecipeIngredients` is String, you can see above in my code: 
`String RecipeIngredients=IngredientsACTV.getText().toString();`

Comment: You need to use it on the key, not on the value. `RecipeIngredients` is the value of a key. You need to use exists() on the coresponding key.